# Vue compiler can't resolve 'vue'

Tags: vue.js, webpack, cdn, vuejs3, vue-loader

Version
3.0.5

Reproduction link
https://github.com/clark-cui/vue3-problem

Steps to reproduce
yarn

npm run dev

What is expected?
devServer work successfully.

What is actually happening?
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vue' in 'F:\workspace_github\vue3-problem'

I didn't use vue-cli or vite to build this reposity.

so I use "vue-loader": "^16.1.2" and "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0" to resolve '.vue'.

If i use cdn to import vue.Then it occur error like this.

If i use npm to import vue.This problem is solved.

This hadn't happen in vue2.I guess it's vue-compiler 's falut.

I want to use vue with cdn.How to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to work with `vue` from CDN you have to configure `externals` to tell `webpack` uses the external one. Additionally you have to refine a few things as following to make it work properly:

```js
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  externals: {
     // tell `webpack` to resolve `vue` from root (window)
     vue: "Vue",
  },
  devServer: {
     // ...
     // might have to turn of this option since it throws error
     // not sure where it comes from though :(
     hot: false,
  }
}
```

Refine the template a bit:

```html
// index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Move the script to here to ensure load `Vue` before your script -->
  <script src="https://cdn.bootcdn.net/ajax/libs/vue/3.0.0/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
  <title>Vue demo</title>
</head>

<body>
  <noscript>
    <strong>error</strong>
  </noscript>
  <div id="app"></div>
</body>

</html>
```